# When is the next Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Okay, so our newest moderator ([HDE 226868](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2153/hde-226868)) was appointed in 2018. So I am wondering, when will our next moderator election occur?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beta sites don't have regular elections like graduated sites. Basically, elections only occur on an as needed basis. I've requested to have an election to bring on another mod, and the CM team says it's slated at some point in the future (no specific dates yet).