# A potential sign that Astronomy is about to graduate?

Tags: discussion, graduation

We've got a bunch of questions over the years about ["Are we graduating soon?"](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/are-we-graduating-sometime-soon) and ["When is the next moderator election?"](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/642/when-is-the-next-moderator-election), etc. Just recently, I noticed that the sidebar for questions now contains a globe icon as well as the "Teams" ad/promotion. Is this a sign that we will graduate soon, or is this added by default in a new SE update?

**Edit (10 seconds later):** Also the UI for questions has been changed just a tiny bit.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362203/334566

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is a network-wide change to all beta sites.